# Progress bar not showing progress swiftly

Tags: android, time, progress-bar

My progress bar is not going swiftly. Below is my code:

```
 _progressBar.setMax(30);

    new CountDownTimer(30000, 100) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            _progressBar.setProgress((int)millisUntilFinished/1000);
            time.setText(String.valueOf((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

This is my progress bar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using the value animator to ease from 0 to 30.

```
    //ease from 0 to 30
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 30);

    //set time length
    valueAnimator.setDuration(30000);

    //control easing type
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        Integer valueAnimatorValue = null;

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
        {
            valueAnimatorValue = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();

             _progressBar.setProgress(valueAnimatorValue);
             time.setText(String.valueOf(valueAnimatorValue);
        }
    });

    valueAnimator.start();
```

Comment: At the end of the Activity onCreate, you might also need to use `valueAnimator.setStartDelay();` so the animator waits till activity is fully loaded.